# How do I create rollover events in actionscript 3.0 in the DOCUMENT CLASS, not the timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, button, flash-cs6, rollover, document-class

I have an animation that I want to function as button and I want it to play the animation when there is a rollover event. I have no clue how to do this.

So far I have this:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class optbtn
    {
        public function optbtn()
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you do know how to do? At the moment I can only assume you have no experience with ActionScript whatsoever.

Comment: I'm extremely new, so I really don't know much. I understand the basics. This is what I'm working on...                               package  {
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 
 public class optbtn {

  public function optbtn() {
   
  }

 }
 
}
 I'm pretty sure I need to add: addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER), but I don't know where to put it or how to make it run

Answer (score 0):

in your constructor would be where I would start, although you could add the listeners in a another function called from your constructor instead.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class optbtn
    {
        public function optbtn()
        {
             addEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRolloverResponse )
        }

        private function onRolloverResponse( e:MouseEvent ):void
        {
            // do something here when rolled over
            // e.target is the object that was rolled over
            // so if you wanted it to play, you might call
            // e.target.gotoAndPlay( 2 );
        }
    }
}
```

Class names are typically capitaized, ie **Optbtn** rather than your **optbtn**

Comment: Just need to make sure that `optbtn` is at least an `EventDispatcher`.

Comment: Good point Marty, this class likely needs to extend MovieClip.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still a bit confused. Is there a way I can stop the animation from automatically playing and only play when I mouse over it? I tried that code and I extended the movie clip, but nothing is changing. I'm sorry, I don't know my way around this program yet.

Comment: Yes, you'd put a stop command on the first frame of your animation movieclip.  Not trying to sound harsh, but it sounds like the level you are at with actionscript is not where you need to be to ask questions here that aren't basically asking someone else to do the work for you.  You should read up on basic actionscript for timeline control, as well as creating classes for extending an object's capabilities.

Comment: I'm posting here as a last resort. I've been looking for tutorials that will help me, but I haven't found anything. Everything I have found is specific to the actions panel and the timeline. If you know of any other resources, then that would be great.